# How to handle situation where old kernel works, new kernel doesn't?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, kubuntu, suspend

If I install Kubuntu 20.04, with network disabled, from a USB stick installer that I prepared just after 20.04 was released, then my laptop suspends and wakes ok (Dell Inspiron 3793, Intel i5 Ice Lake, Nvidia MX230).

But if I use the same USB installer with network enabled, or use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` after installing, then my laptop will not wake correctly from suspend - I get a black screen.

It is ok if I boot the upgraded installation using the old kernel using the grub menu.

Original kernel: 5.4.0-26 (working)
New kernel: 5.4.0-53 (not working)

So short term I need to use the old kernel but I would still like to upgrade. Will the upgrade process ever delete the old kernel automatically? Can I make grub boot with the old kernel by default, so I don't have to go through the menu, without the upgrade process changing it back?

And I probably need to report a kernel bug. But I've looked at the kernel changelogs and there are hundreds of changes netween 5.4.0-26 and -53. (The upgrade included not only new versions of Nvidia drivers (450) but appears to have new versions of the original 440, but the old kernel works with the new 450 drivers, so it would appear to be a kernel issue) So how to proceed?

Update: output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` is `1.11.0`. (This is a new laptop that came with Windows installed; the one thing I did before obliterating Windows is a bios update from Dell's web site).

Update 2: Output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="SDD 128Gb System" UUID="eecfa2fb-0733-46f5-96a7-e050724ae2a3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d6f0f6e9-3d9f-48c3-bc1b-709549a864bc"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="3795-6278" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="292dce4c-e774-4a68-974e-9460f49c3409"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="HDD 1Tb Data" UUID="8dddb3ce-30e8-4356-8b34-62c340b74807" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="445e5b9a-cb9f-a04c-b062-67b2b75c4a71"
```

Output of `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

(I don't know why it says that, the GUI Info Centre tool says I have a 2Gb swapfile. But it is not in /etc/fstab - is there another way of configuring a swapfile?)

Output of `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:

```
cat: /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume: No such file or directory
```

A new 5.4.0.54 kernel came through `sudo apt upgrade` today, but no change. Nvidia MX230 - I have tried all available drivers presented to me - there were several - and a new one that came through `sudo apt upgrade` yesterday - but no difference (I have also tried Nuveau with and without nomodeset.) In a previous install on the same laptop while investigating this problem I configured a 20Gb swapfile and I could hibernate *and resume* ok. It is just resume from suspend that does not work with newer kernels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @karel partly, thank you. The `GRUB_DEFAULT=` line in `/etc/default/grub` sets the default kernel it will boot with. But what happens when there is an updated kernel in the update process, and can old kernels be uninstalled automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/)

Comment: You usually have to give the okay to removed kernels, but most times they will not be listed fully, so have to be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GRUB**

re: "*Can I make grub boot with the old kernel by default?*"

Yes. Edit /etc/default/grub and change/add the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then `sudo update-grub`.

Now, GRUB will remember the last booted kernel, until such time that you select a different one.

**old kernels**

re: "*Can old kernels be uninstalled automatically?*"

This is now done via the `Software Updater` application.

**BIOS**

Dell Inspiron 3793

re: "*Original kernel: 5.4.0-26 (working) New kernel: 5.4.0-53 (not working)*"

Newer versions of Ubuntu/kernel seem to prefer that the latest BIOS is installed.

You have BIOS 1.11.0.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.12.0, dated Nov 3, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-17-3793-laptop/drivers) or [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=j5595&oscode=wt64a&productcode=inspiron-17-3793-laptop).

Installation instructions are [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=j5595&oscode=wt64a&productcode=inspiron-17-3793-laptop).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to notice there is a new BIOS available. Sadly it didn't help though. (Good to see that BIOSes like this can now be updated through the BIOS itself rather than needing Windows!)

However the other grub fixes mean that I now have a fully functioning laptop that will sleep when the lid is shut and wake up again reasonably quickly when it is opened.

Comment: @B.Tanner Have you tried the 5.4.0-53 kernel with the newer BIOS? Is the issue just with resuming? Show me `sudo blkid` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Do you have Nidia? If so, what model, and what version driver?

Comment: Info added to question! A new kernel came today, it did not help but `apt upgrade` did not remove my old (working) one, so I am happy for the time being!

Comment: What USB/external/video devices do you have connected?

Comment: None - no external devices, it's a new laptop as delivered. `lsusb` lists an internal web cam and Qualcom Atheros (wifi?).

Comment: @B.Tanner It sounds like you've got a working machine, now. Hopefully some newer kernels will run on your machine in the near future.