# Screen goes crazy with noise and ubuntu freezes

Tags: 20.04, display, gdm

**Description:**
Ubuntu screen gets crazy with black and white "noise", this has happened several times. It seems that Ubuntu is also frozen in this state because I cannot connect with teamviewer(I have assigned this laptop to my Teamviewer account), this might also mean that it is not a display driver issue (not sure though). 
Here is a photo of the problem:
[image]
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnISR-hGc2aI8io9ih76mhFer4IE?e=sbt4XQ

**Logs:**
Important: https://pastebin.com/DFSyS6jw
System: https://pastebin.com/8ff66GWw
Hardware logs: https://pastebin.com/ydZLAznK

**Info:**
-OS: Ubuntu 20.04 (64bit)
-Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)
-Kernel: 5.0.0-1070-oem-osp1
-Laptop: Dell Inspiron 3593

Comment: where did that kernel come from?  You should be on something like 5.4.0-54.generic using the standard install.

Comment: This kernel is the one that came with this laptop. I have not updated kernel because newer ones cause another issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend

Comment: This is a *Dell-provided* installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: I think so. I have tried many kernels and this oem kernel is the only one that does not cause the no suspend issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and it started yesterday. Every ~2 hours this happens and I have to power off and on my laptop. Ubuntu 20.04, Dell Precision 3520. Did you manage to fix the problem @freeweblife?