# Won't wake up - Ubuntu 21.10 - Dell XPS 17

Tags: suspend, dell, 21.10

Hardware: Dell XPS 17 laptop 9710 (brand new)

Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10

Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz × 16

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (TGL GT1)

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
```

Problem: when the laptop goes to sleep, I cannot wake it up.  Neither opening the lid nor tapping the power button will wake it up.

Workaround: hold the power button for 40 seconds.  After doing this, I can tap the power button and get it to reboot.  Unsatisfactory because I lose any open applications.

Comment: Do you have swap space defined? `free` will tell you. To successfully hibernate you need as much swap as you have memory (`sudo lshw -C memory`).

Comment: That's looking like it might be the issue. Free reports 16103132 of memory and 2097148 of swap.

Comment: That is likely *not* the issue: "hibernate" needs swap space, but "sleep" does not: everything is kept in memory. "hibernate" is disabled by default, because it does not work well on many machines. "sleep", however, usually works, and if not, it mostly is because you have a proprietary graphics card like nvidea: edit your question and include info on your graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this command worked ([found from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298222)):

```bsh
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

I have a Dell XPS 15 9510, on which I installed Ubuntu 21.10.

I had the same problem from the beginning: when making the laptop sleep, it displayed a black screen, and never woke up. The only way to get something was to press the power button during 10 seconds to force the computer power off.

I had also another problem: most of the time the computer was not shutting down. When asking to shut down it stopped to a black screen with "Ubuntu" displayed. Same thing here: the only solution to shut down was 10 seconds on the power button.

I think the problem was that the NVIDIA driver was missing (I have a GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile, in addition to the Intel UHD Graphics). Before the command I didn't have anything in `Software & updates -> Additional drivers`.
After the command I had several NVIDIA drivers, with the first one selected for me.

Comment: The other symptoms you describe are also occurring for me. Thanks. Will update with whether this fixed my issue.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you.