# Problem waking from suspend and screen blank on Ubuntu Dell laptop Precision 3570

Tags: dell, power-management, laptop, screen

I have a strange problem where I am sometimes unable to wake my computer from suspend or screen blank using the keyboard or power button. The only thing that does work reliably is closing and reopening the lid twice.

I have tried the top answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1298222/575953

I have tried updating the BIOS to the latest version

I had upgraded using do-release-upgrade to 22.04 before noticing this problem.

Comment: I have also now tried this answer and it seems to work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1383940/5759