# Ubuntu doesn't wake up after standby

Tags: suspend, standby

I have the last version of Ubuntu. When my computer goes in standby because I don't use it, I was not able to wake it up. If I move my mouse or touch my keyboard, the screen wake up and show a red/orange (Ubuntu color) but nothing else and I need to shut down the computer by staying on the on/off button and start up again... Any solutions ?

When I use it and choose "suspend" and try to wake up just after it works but i wait too long it doesn't work.

config of the computer (it's a custom):

cpu : AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX 32-Core Processor

motherboard : X399 AORUS PRO-CF

graphics : GeForce RTX 2080 Ti

RAM : DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns

i have a ssd and a HDD with these partitions :

[image]

Comment: What is the make/model of the computer (or laptop?) that you're using (please edit your question to include this information)? Have you searched this community for your issue, as there are many related issues already discussed and depending on your computer/laptop, your issue may have already been resolved. [You may want to review this issue for some options/troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/q/1298198/32664).