# Ubuntu won't wake up from Suspend on Dell G5 15 5590

Tags: 22.04, suspend, dell, power-management

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS since 2–3 weeks on my Dell laptop (which came with Windows by default). It is a Dell G5 15 5590 from 2019 with an Intel i7 9750H and GTX 1660 Ti. I upgraded the RAM to 32 Gb, and replaced the default SSD.

I have an issue regarding system Suspend. My system used *s2idle" by default. It does not work well at all, when the laptop is going to sleep, it wakes up for no reason, then won't go back to sleep automatically, for unknown reason (like something is keeping it alive). So, I switched the sleep mode from "s2idle" to "sleep". Now, it works better, the laptop won't wake up for no reason, and the battery does not wear as quickly as before, other than the fact that it takes longer to wake up.

Today, I had my laptop plugged to an external display using the HDMI port. I put my laptop to "Suspend" then, I unplugged my laptop from the monitor as well as everything else (mouse, external keyboard, Ethernet, headset). I put it in my bag, and 2 hours later, opened the lid again. I pressed the power button to wake the laptop (I did not plugged it to anything, not even the charger), the keyboard's LED turned on, the screen turned on also, but the screen stayed plain black.

It is a recurring problem, I even had this issue on the s2idle mode. I would like to fix it, but I do not really know where to start. My UEFI is up-to-date from latest version from Dell website. The issue does not happens everytime, it is quite random. Usually it works, but here it didn't, which is even more complicated to try and replicate.

I'm not sure what information I can give you, I ran this comand that I found on ask ubuntu. I'm not sure how to parse it.

> journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'

Logs from journalctl: https://gist.github.com/Deewens/7bf15d2b26fdd878a430c009f1c6dfc5

(I cannot put it directly in the post because it won't le met Post due to character limitations)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate but are any of the tips on this answer any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend

Comment: Thanks! I'll try some of these tips and see if it makes any difference